# Missing CMDLETS in Powershell v4 on Windows 7 SP1

Tags: powershell

I've installed .NET 4.5.1 and then WMF 4.0 on my Windows 7 Enterprise machine with the sole intention of using the PrintManagement cmdlets in PoSH v4 but they seem to be missing. 
$PSVersionTable returns:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18408
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

There are many cmdlets (including the PrintManagement cmdlets) that are only available on Windows 8+ -- they are a part of the OS, not PowerShell itself. It's frustrating, but many times when people refer to new cmdlets available in PowerShell version 3 or 4, they are really talking about new modules available in Windows 8/8.1.